# How to reduce android studio build time when Testing to a real Device

Tags: java, android, gradle, build-time

For you guys who might have computers that have less memory resources, Less than the **8GB**  recommended by android studio docs, I have a solution on how to reduce the build that android studio consumes while trying to build an debug app to run in your real device.
Instead of using the run Icon just open your terminal that is usually beside the logcat at the bottom sheet and run this-:

```
Gradlew installDebug
```

Saved me alot of time. My machine is a has **4GB** of ram and with that it takes less than a minute to build unlike 10 mins before i stumbled on this method

you should not that

1. the first time will take longer. almost the normal amountwhen you use the run button
2. The con of this method is that, the app does not start automatically you have to launch it yourself
   Hope this saves someone!!!!!
   [image: check this screen shot on how fast it is building[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a11v.png)